# Why does getRunningTasks does not identify RecentApplicationsActivity as a running task?

Tags: android, activity-manager

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(5);
```

This is the code used in my home screen app to get the running activities.

When the `HOME` key is long pressed, the recently used app list (with an activity named `RecentApplicationsActivity`) comes up. but it's not being listed in "tasks" in the above code.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: this may be because the android system is avoiding it intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

Because its not an Activity but a Dialog which shows the RecentApplications. Its called RecentApplicationsDialog.
You can check the code in AOSP.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/RecentApplicationsDialog.java

This Dialog is handled by the PhoneWindowManager which is managed by WindowManagerService.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java

```
private void handleLongPressOnHome() {

        if (mLongPressOnHomeBehavior < 0) {
            mLongPressOnHomeBehavior
                    = mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.config_longPressOnHomeBehavior);
            if (mLongPressOnHomeBehavior < LONG_PRESS_HOME_NOTHING ||
                    mLongPressOnHomeBehavior > LONG_PRESS_HOME_RECENT_SYSTEM_UI) {
                mLongPressOnHomeBehavior = LONG_PRESS_HOME_NOTHING;
            }
        }

        if (mLongPressOnHomeBehavior != LONG_PRESS_HOME_NOTHING) {
            performHapticFeedbackLw(null, HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS, false);
            sendCloseSystemWindows(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS);

            // Eat the longpress so it won't dismiss the recent apps dialog when
            // the user lets go of the home key
            mHomeLongPressed = true;
        }

        if (mLongPressOnHomeBehavior == LONG_PRESS_HOME_RECENT_DIALOG) {
            showOrHideRecentAppsDialog(RECENT_APPS_BEHAVIOR_SHOW_OR_DISMISS);
        } else if (mLongPressOnHomeBehavior == LONG_PRESS_HOME_RECENT_SYSTEM_UI) {
            try {
                IStatusBarService statusbar = getStatusBarService();
                if (statusbar != null) {
                    statusbar.toggleRecentApps();
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Slog.e(TAG, "RemoteException when showing recent apps", e);
                // re-acquire status bar service next time it is needed.
                mStatusBarService = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The Context used to show this Dialog does not belongs to any normal task, instead system context is used to show this Dialog.